# Reference request: Continuous cyclic/Hochschild cohomology of compactly supported functions

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

It is a well-known result by Connes that the continuous cyclic cohomology of the algebra of smooth functions $C^\infty(M)$ on a manifold $M$ is of the shape

$$HC^\bullet(C^\infty(M)) = Z_n(M) \oplus H_{n-2}(M) \oplus H_{n-4}(M) \oplus \dots$$

where $Z_n$ denotes the closed de Rham currents and $H_k$ denotes the $k$-th de Rham homology, see e.g. Lectures on Cyclic Cohomology by Masoud Khalkhali.

Consider now the algebra of compactly supported functions $C^\infty_c(M)$ with the inductive limit topology. Is there a corresponding result for continuous cyclic cohomology of this space, and can someone provide a reference? It seems like an obvious problem to consider, but I have not found a clear reference, and it also does not seem to fit into any of the general results (e.g. there are results on "topologically finitely generated algebras", but this does not seem to be one).

Alternatively, I think I could also content myself with a source for the Hochschild cohomology of $C^\infty_c(M)$, since the cyclic cohomology follows from that. In the paper "The homology of algebras of pseudo-differential symbols and the non-commutative residue" by Brylinski and Getzler, they cite the 1985-paper by Connes to write

$$HH_\bullet(C^\infty_c(M), C^\infty_c(M)) = \Omega_c^\bullet(M),$$

but I can not find that statement in their reference.